# Solving differential equation with small parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following equation

$$\frac{x}{x+1}\frac{d^{2}\left(\phi^2\right)}{dx^{2}}+\frac{2x+1}{(x+1)^{2}}\frac{d\left(\phi^2\right)}{dx}=\frac{1}{3\phi}$$

with $x\ll1$ and $\frac{d\phi^2}{dx} = 2\phi\frac{d\phi}{dx}$

**My Answer**
for $x\ll1$, the above equation becomes

$$x\frac{d^{2}\left(\phi^2\right)}{dx^{2}}+\frac{d\left(\phi^2\right)}{dx}=\frac{1}{3\phi}$$

I tried to solve the equation with no second derivative and I got $\phi(x)=k x^{1/3}$, Is it possible to solve the above equation?

Comment: What does $\frac{d^{2}\phi^{2}}{dx^{2}}$ mean? Do you mean $\frac{d^{2}\phi}{dx^{2}}$? Same for the $\frac{d\phi^{2}}{dx}$ term.

Comment: $\frac{d\phi^2}{dx}$ here means $2\phi\frac{d\phi}{dx}$

Comment: My guess is if $x$ is small, the second derivative term will be close to $0$ and you get a first-order equation.